# How to get all the values from a key using Karate

Tags: karate

A Karate beginner here

This is my Scenario Outline that I am trying to use

```
Scenario Outline: API Should Support Sorting
    Given path 'mypathHere'
    And params {sortColumn: <sort>, isActive:1}
    When method Get
    Then status 200
    * def data = karate.jsonPath(response,"$..<sortColumn>")
    * def dataSorted = karate.sort(data)
    And match data == dataSorted

    Examples:
        | sort      | sortColumn |
        | name      | name       |
        | unitCode  | code       |
        | shortName | shortName  |
```

I have a response with an object that looks like this

```
 [
        {
            "type": "unit",
            "id": 1004,
            "name": "Name 1",
            "code": "Code Name 1",
            "shortName": "Short Name 1"
        },
        {
            "type": "unit",
            "id": 615,
            "name": "Name 2",
            "code": "Code 2",
            "shortName": "Short Name 2"
        },
        {
            "type": "unit",
            "id": 1071,
            "name": "Name 3",
            "code": "Code 3",
            "shortName": "Short Name 3"

        }
]
```

I need to get a list of all the values for one of the keys.

I know that i can use this approach

```
* def data = karate.jsonPath(response,"$..name")
```

But I wonder if there's a **Karate way** that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## First solution

```
* def data = response.map((item) => item.<sortColumn>)
* print data
```

## second solution

```
* def data2 = $response[*].<sortColumn>
* print data2

Examples:
  | sort      | sortColumn |
  | name      | name       |
  | unitCode  | code       |
  | shortName | shortName  |
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd argue you *are* doing it the "karate" way as you are literally using the karate key word in your example to get the expected values. There is nothing wrong with your approach. Here is another way to go about it using karate.map

```
* def key = <sortColumn>
* def values = karate.map(response, function(item) { return item[key] })
```

Comment: Thank you, great way to show that there are many ways to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 1):

That's a fun challenge. Here's my solution:

```
* def result = {}
* def keys = ['id', 'name', 'code', 'shortName']
* keys.forEach(x => result[x] = response.map(y => y[x]))
* print result
```

It will give you a single object, with the keys and values combined. You should be able to easily combine sorting if needed.

Comment: Thank you, that's an interesting solution that I might use in the other tests where I need to deal with more data.